# How to use min and max width in Tailwind media query?

Tags: tailwind-css

How can one use both min and max width in a media query using Tailwind Css 3?

My config:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["index.html"],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'sm': '768px',
      'md': '1024px',
      'lg': '1440px'
    },
  },
}
```

It's no problem doing for example:

```
@media screen(md) {}
```

But how can i incorporate a max-width in it as well?

I want the output css to look like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: some px) and (max-width: some px) {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are talking about inside your CSS, you can just write the media query CSS as you have already written – you don't necessarily need to reach for some Tailwind syntax.

Comment: I'm talking about that, yes. I'm aware of that, but want to know how and if it's possible to do using Tailwind syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the answer if I have well understood your question.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-breakpoint-range

For instance :

```
md:max-lg:flex
```

for a range between md and lg.

Comment: Hi! Yes, works in that context. But how would you write it in your css file?

Comment: tailwind  CLI compile like that : @media not all and (min-width: 1024px). As it is written in the doc. You can use arbitrary values too : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#arbitrary-values

Comment: the result of these arbitrary values in css : 

media (max-width: 600px) {
  .max-\[600px\]\:bg-sky-300 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(125 211 252 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }
}

media (min-width: 320px) {
  .min-\[320px\]\:text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

with a "@" in front of media